# Swift- Using Delegation to append data to TableView within CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates

I have a CollectionViewController named `yearOne`that looks something like this:
[image]

When you click the add button for each quarter cell it leads you to `SearchPage`:
[image]

I used delegation to append the data clicked on `SearchPage` to `yearOne`
The delegation seems to work and data seems to append as I tried the print(vc.data) but it doesn't seem to show up on the tableView when backed into `yearOne` viewcontroller through `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` Am I doing something wrong?

```
import UIKit

class yearOne: UICollectionViewController, coursesDelegate {

    let customCellIdentifier = "cellID"
    let customCellIdentifier2 = "cellID2"
    let customCellIdentifier3 = "cellID3"
    let customCellIdentifier4 = "cellID4"

    let quarters = [
        customLabel (title: "Fall Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Winter Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Spring Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Summer Quarter")
    ]

    let vc = fallQuarterCell()
    let vc2 = winterQuarterCell()
    let vc3 = springQuarterCell()
    let vc4 = summerQuarterCell()

    func sendDataBackFall(data: String) {
        vc.data.append(data)
        print(vc.data)
        //UserDefaults.standard.set(vc.data, forKey: "SavedArray")

    }
    func sendDataBackWinter(data2: String) {
        vc2.data.append(data2)
    }
    func sendDataBackSpring(data3: String) {
        vc3.data.append(data3)
    }
    func sendDataBackSummer(data4: String) {
        vc4.data.append(data4)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        self.collectionView!.register(fallQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier)//
        self.collectionView!.register(winterQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier2)
        self.collectionView!.register(springQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier3)
        self.collectionView!.register(summerQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier4)

        navigationItem.title = "Year One"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return quarters.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! fallQuarterCell
            cell1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
            cell1.layer.borderWidth = 2
            cell1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell1.quarters = self.quarters[0]
            return cell1
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1){
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier2, for: indexPath) as! winterQuarterCell
            cell2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            cell2.layer.borderWidth = 2
            cell2.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell2.quarters = self.quarters[1]
            return cell2
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2){
            let cell3 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier3, for: indexPath) as! springQuarterCell
            cell3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            cell3.layer.borderWidth = 2
            cell3.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell3.quarters = self.quarters[2]
            return cell3
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 3){
            let cell4 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier4, for: indexPath) as! summerQuarterCell
            cell4.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            cell4.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell4.quarters = self.quarters[3]
            return cell4
        }
        else{
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            let destination = SearchPage()
            destination.delegate = self
            destination.tag = sender.tag
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        case 1:
            let destination = SearchPage()
            destination.delegate = self
            destination.tag = sender.tag
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        case 2:
            let destination = SearchPage()
            destination.delegate = self
            destination.tag = sender.tag
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        case 3:
            let destination = SearchPage()
            destination.delegate = self
            destination.tag = sender.tag
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        default:
            let destination = SearchPage()
            destination.delegate = self
            destination.tag = sender.tag
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        }

    }
}

extension yearOne : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (view.frame.width - 30)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 200)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 10, bottom: 30, right: 10)
    }

}


class fallQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //var data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SavedArray") as? [String] ?? [String]()

    var data : [String] = []

//    func load(){
//        if let loadeddata: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SavedArray") as? [String] {
//            data = loadeddata
//            tableView.reloadData()
//        }
//    }

    let cellId = "coursesName"

    let tableView:UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return tableView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(tableView)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        contentView.addSubview(quarterLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(addButton)

        quarterLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        quarterLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        quarterLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: quarterLabel.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        addButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        addButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        addButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0){
                data.remove(at: 0)
                //UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedArray")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 1){
                data.remove(at: 1)
                //UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedArray")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 2){
                data.remove(at: 2)
                //UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedArray")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 3){
                data.remove(at: 3)
                //UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedArray")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 4){
                data.remove(at: 4)
                //UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedArray")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //add class information???
    }

    var quarters: customLabel? {
        didSet {
            guard let quarters = quarters else {return}
            quarterLabel.text = quarters.title
        }
    }

    let quarterLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()//frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: -75, width: 300, height: 50))
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        //label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    let addButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()//frame: CGRect(x: 345, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30))
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "addicon"), for: .normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        button.tag = 0
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yearOne.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()


    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I also have the

`class winterQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

`class springQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

`class summerQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

similar to fallQuarterCell but excluded it.

```
import UIKit

protocol coursesDelegate {
    func sendDataBackFall(data: String)
    func sendDataBackWinter(data2: String)
    func sendDataBackSpring(data3: String)
    func sendDataBackSummer(data4: String)
}

class SearchPage: UITableViewController {

    var delegate: coursesDelegate?

    let cellId = "course"

    var allCourses : NSArray = NSArray()
    var filteredCourses = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    var tag: Int?
    let vc = fallQuarterCell()
    let vc2 = winterQuarterCell()
    let vc3 = springQuarterCell()
    let vc4 = summerQuarterCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let courses : CourseList = CourseList()
        allCourses = courses.coursesList

        navigationItem.title = "Select Courses"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        //let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add Course", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
        //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button1


        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Courses"
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

            tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
        })()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if  (resultSearchController.isActive) {
            return filteredCourses.count
        }
        else{
            return allCourses.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        if (resultSearchController.isActive) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredCourses[indexPath.row]
            return cell
         }
         else {
            let courses = self.allCourses[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = courses as? String
            return cell
         }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if (tag == 0){
            if (resultSearchController.isActive){
//                vc.data.append(filteredCourses[indexPath.row])
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc.data, forKey: "SavedArray")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                let data = filteredCourses[indexPath.row]
                delegate?.sendDataBackFall(data: data)
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
            else{
//                vc.data.append(allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String)
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc.data, forKey: "SavedArray")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                let data = allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String
                delegate?.sendDataBackFall(data: data)
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
        }

        else if (tag == 1){
            if (resultSearchController.isActive){
//                vc2.data.append(filteredCourses[indexPath.row])
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc2.data, forKey: "SavedArray2")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                let data = filteredCourses[indexPath.row]
                delegate?.sendDataBackWinter(data2: data)
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            else{
//                vc2.data.append(allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String)
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc2.data, forKey: "SavedArray2")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                let data = allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String
                delegate?.sendDataBackWinter(data2: data)
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }

        else if (tag == 2){
            if (resultSearchController.isActive){
//                vc3.data.append(filteredCourses[indexPath.row])
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc3.data, forKey: "SavedArray3")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
            else{
//                vc3.data.append(allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String)
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc3.data, forKey: "SavedArray3")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }

        else if (tag == 3){
            if (resultSearchController.isActive){
//                vc4.data.append(filteredCourses[indexPath.row])
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc4.data, forKey: "SavedArray4")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
            else{
//                vc4.data.append(allCourses[indexPath.row] as! String)
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(vc4.data, forKey: "SavedArray4")
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }

    }

    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
      return resultSearchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }
}

extension SearchPage: UISearchResultsUpdating {

  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
      filteredCourses.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

      let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
      let array = (allCourses as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
      filteredCourses = array as! [String]

      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }

}
```

I commented out the UsersDefault.standard.set.... because the data itself doesn't seem to refresh and display in the tableView atm

Comment: I think the height of your collectionViewCell should be dynamic and not hardcoded to 200. What may be happening is, the data is adding, but the collectionView cell is not expanding as per the new tableviewHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Check at your cellForRow method. I don't believe you set the text anywhere.

Comment: I have the ```func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }``` in `yearOne`